# Is is possible to say these sentences in a formal context in British English?

Tags: grammar

> Has he not got his new bicycle?
>
> Have you not got your book yet?

I think that the above ones are the same as these in informal context:

> Hasn't he got his new bicycle?
>
> Haven't you got your book yet?

Comment: At school, we were told (50 years ago) (UK) to avoid the word 'got' as 'being rather uncouth' (the wit of the teacher, "Never use 'get' - get another word!" ensured it stuck). The word _is_ overused, but is also very useful. In a refined register, or perhaps that should be precious, one _could_ say 'Has he not received his new bicycle?' ('Has he not brought his new bicycle?' is fine) etc. But I can't imagine many settings where I'd choose to avoid any of your four versions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't disagree; but, answering the question in the title, I would say, "no, those sentences are not quite formal".

Comment: I say all are fine in formal context (in American English).

Comment: I'll make sure only to be formal in the US then.

Comment: _Have you still not come in possession of your book?_ :) Legalese. ^__^

Comment: _Have you as yet not come in possession of your book?_ Turned up to eleven :)

Answer (score 1):

You would actually want to use the word '[gotten](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gotten)'.  I would still say that it borders on the informal.  Rather, I would use something more along the lines of:

> Has he not received his new bicycle?
>
> Have you not had a chance to acquire your book?
>
> Have you not aquired your book?

Comment: Perhaps you speak like an American. They usually use "gotten" instead of "got". But the verb in case is "to have got", not the verb "to have" and "to get". It is the Present Tense I'm talking about not the Present Perfect :)

Comment: user36663: That is a difference I was unaware of.  I am American and to me using 'got' in this context isn't quite alien, but I would have considered it uneducated. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: @user36663: that is most certainly incorrect.  It would be "doesn't he have his new bicycle"

Comment: Jacob and user36663, Americans use the word 'gotten' a lot. British people normally only use it when saying *ill-gotten* or *forgotten*.

Comment: The question specifically asked about "British English". As Tristan says, "gotten" is not in common usage as a part tense of "got" in BrE - and most certainly not "in a formal context" as specified in the question.

Comment: @TrevorD: Hence the reason I said it was informal, and recommended the alternatives.

Comment: But the stipulation renders inaccurate your bold statement "You would actually want to use the word 'gotten'." 'Not in common usage' and 'informal' are very often totally different categorisations.

Answer (score 1):

Generally avoid use of the word 'got' in the context of having.

> He has a bicycle

this implies he owns or is holding a bicycle. 
Whereas

> He got a bicycle

states he undertook the action of retrieving a bicycle, but may no longer `have` it.

A useful way to remember the difference is:

> I have a coffee, the barista got it for me

In your case it's unclear whether you're asking if he/you got the bicycle/book (for you), or whether he *has* the bicycle/book.

By rephrasing the statement correctly you can clarify the statements as:

> Does he have his new bicycle?
>
> Do you have your book yet?

or

> Did he get his new bicycle?
>
> Did you get your book yet?

These both have the additional benefit of removing the unnecessary negative.